# Consulta SQl con inner join para filtrar datos en base al usuario que ingresa al sistema

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Teng una Base de Datos con el sigueinte esquema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El usuario pertenece a un establecimiento, el establecimiento pertenece a un municipio, el departamento tiene muchos municipios y el municipio tiene muchos cantones, entonces quier una consulta SQL que me devuelva todos los cantones de todos lo municipios asociados al departamento donde esta el establecimiento.

he probado con :

```
select ctn.* from ctl_canton ctn left join ctl_municipio muni on ctn.id_municipio=muni.id left join 
       ctl_establecimiento est on muni.id=est.id_municipio
       where est.id=10;
```

pero solo me trae los cantones del municipio donde esta el establecimiento y tambien quiero los cantones de sus municipios hermanos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como siempre digo, el problema en estas querys, es no hacerla por pedazos. Tratar de hacer todo de un tiron sin siquiera analizar lo que se quiere.

Veamos...

Queremos obtener primero el departamento del municipio. Entonces empecemos por hacer la query que obtenga eso:

```
SELECT 
    d.id 
FROM 
    ctl_establecimiento e LEFT JOIN ctl_municipio m ON e.id_municipo = m.id
    LEFT JOIN ctl_departamento d ON m.id_departamento = d.id
WHERE
    e.id=10
```

Esto va a traer, el departamento para ese establecimiento. Ahora solo necesitamos usar esa consulta, como condicion de join para traer los cantones. Entoces si llamamos a toda esa consulta J, podriamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    c.*
FROM 
    (TODA LA CONSULTA ANTERIOR) J LEFT JOIN ctl_municipio m ON J.id = m.id_departamento 
    LEFT JOIN ctl_canton c ON m.id = c.id_municipio
```

y de esa forma, tendrias lo que vos queres.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta la he acomodado a mi necesidad y funciona muy bine.

Comment: Perfecto. Recuerda como funciona el sitio. Las gracias sobran ;) sin embargo si la respuesta te sirvio, aceptala.  o votala positivo. o mucho mejor las dos cosas ;). Revisa el [tour]